# php preg_match doesn't give expected result

Tags: php, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I expect this one to return (bool)True or int(1)

```
echo var_dump(preg_match('/(<[tT][eE][xX][tT][aA][rR][eE][aA][^<>]*>)(.*?)(<\/[tT][eE][xX][tT][aA][rR][eE][aA]>)/', 
    "<textarea id='field-static_content' name='static_content' class='texteditor' ><p>
any content<p></textarea>"));
```

But I get int(0) as a result.
I try to match any string with "`<textarea`" (non case sensitive) followed by any other character but "<" and ">", followed by ">", followed by any other character, and then ended by "`</textarea>`" non case sensitive

Do anyone know what's wrong with my regex pattern?

Comment: RegEx are not reliable for parsing HTML. Instead use parser such as simplehtmldom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Comment: Parse this string, but in the future, don't use `[tT][eE]` thingy's to make a patterns case-insensitive, instead use `'/textarea/i'`<-- the i is the case-Insensitive flag, also: it's important to know that neigh on _every_ char has a special meaning depending on the context in which it's used, not in the least `<` and `>`, which you seem to forget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the [`/s`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) flag. Your input text contains a linebreak, which is why `.*?` won't find it per default.

More importantly you are missing the `/i` flag for case-insensitivity. No need to write `[aA][bB]`...

Answer (score 1):

It's the line break. Check [Pattern Modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), 's' and also 'i'.